# Why is my password reset expiration test failing? (Ruby on Rails Tutorial)

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby, testing, erb

I am following the Ruby on Rails Tutorial for Rails 7. I am doing chapter 12.3.3, the second exercise, where it tells me:

> Write an integration test for the expired password reset branch in Listing 12.16 by filling in the template shown in Listing 12.22. (This code introduces response.body, which returns the full HTML body of the page.) There are many ways to test for the result of an expiration, but the method suggested by Listing 12.22 is to (case-insensitively) check that the response body includes the word “expired”.

**Listing 12.22 (password_resets_test.rb)**

```
class PasswordResets < ActionDispatch::IntegrationTest

  def setup
    ActionMailer::Base.deliveries.clear
    @user = users(:one)
  end
end

class ExpiredToken < PasswordResets

  def setup
    super
    # Create a password-reset token.
    post password_resets_path,
         params: { password_reset: { email: @user.email } }
    @reset_user = assigns(:user)
    # Expire the token by hand.
    @reset_user.update_attribute(:reset_sent_at, 3.hours.ago)
    # Attempt to update the user's password.
    patch password_reset_path(@reset_user.reset_token),
          params: { email: @reset_user.email,
                    user: { password: 'foobar',
                            password_confirmation: 'foobar' } }
  end
end

class ExpiredTokenTest < ExpiredToken

  test 'should redirect to the password-reset page' do
    assert_redirected_to new_password_reset_url
  end

  test "should include the word 'expired' on the password-reset page" do
    follow_redirect!
    assert_match /expired/i, response.body # ❌ THIS IS FAILING ❌
  end
end
```

I've been repeatedly going through the chapter, and actually managed to successfully implement the test in another app, for which I promptly copied and pasted over code to see if I could find a typo, but I can't find it.

In order to not make this post too long, I will try to only include relevant code to the expiration issue...

**routes.rb**

```
resources :password_resets, only: [:new, :create, :edit, :update]
```

**password_resets_controller.rb**

```
class PasswordResetsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :get_user, only: [:edit, :update]
  before_action :valid_user, only: [:edit, :update]
  before_action :check_expiration, only: [:edit, :update]


  def update
    if params[:user][:password].empty?
      @user.errors.add(:password, "can't be empty")
      render 'edit', status: :unprocessable_entity
    elsif @user.update(user_params)
      @user.forget
      reset_session
      log_in @user
      flash[:success] = 'Password has been reset.'
      redirect_to @user
    else
      render 'edit', status: :unprocessable_entity
    end
  end

  def check_expiration
    if @user.password_reset_expired?
      flash[:danger] = 'Password reset has expired.'
      redirect_to new_password_reset_url
    end
  end
end
```

**Another test in password_resets_test.rb that passes**

```
def setup
  ActionMailer::Base.deliveries.clear
  @user = users(:one)
  post password_resets_path,
       params: { password_reset: { email: @user.email } }
  @reset_user = assigns(:user)
end


test 'update with valid password and confirmation' do
  patch password_reset_path(@reset_user.reset_token),
        params: { email: @reset_user.email,
                  user: { password: 'foobaz',
                          password_confirmation: 'foobaz' } }
  assert is_logged_in?
  assert_not flash.empty?
  assert_redirected_to @reset_user
end
```

**password_resets/new.html.erb**

```
<% provide(:title, "Forgot password") %>
<h1>Forgot password</h1>

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
    <%= form_with(url: password_resets_path, scope: :password_reset) do |f| %>
      <%= f.label :email %>
      <%= f.email_field :email, class: 'form-control' %>

      <%= f.submit "Submit", class: "btn btn-primary" %>
    <% end %>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I would add a `puts response.body` to the test with before the line `assert_match /expired/i, response.body` to see that the response actually looks like when it doesn't include the word you are looking for.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).